# What do you call airy falsetto like low voice?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, vocal-cords, bass-voice, falsetto

I'd like to know the term to call the airy low or mid voice as like the high airy sound is called "falsetto", since falsetto is used only in high notes.

Comment: Can you post an audio example?

Comment: I’d think low Bee Gees or Green Gartside, Scritti Politti, Cupid £ Psyche album would be good examples. idk what you’d call it either:)

Comment: Welcome! Can you edit the question to explain a bit more? I'm not sure whether you're asking mostly about a part of the range—like "What do you call the part just below falsetto"—or about a style of singing, like "What do you call singing with a breathy tone, regardless of range." Also, although you used the tag "bass-voice," please specify if you're talking only about basses or about all voices.

Comment: Was on phone before - this is what I was thinking the OP might mean - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7Mk_JgesEM - I used to be able to do that [can't do it convincingly any more], never known what it's called. I did the entire Bee Gees catalogue on Pioneer Karaoke vocals way back then, kind of got me warmed up to handle it ;))

Answer (score 2):

"airy" is not what defines falsetto: falsetto refers to singing in a particular configuration of the larynx where the relaxed vocal fold muscles are stretched by outward rather than inner tension.  Good vocal closure is harder to achieve in lower falsetto ranges, but the degree of "airiness" depends on training, intent, and of course pitch.  Once the base of the vocal fold muscles gets involved as well, closure becomes easier, the achievable lower range is extended significantly and chest voice resonances set in that are not occuring with the simpler oscillatory action in falsetto.

A lack of closure is not a defining mark of a register, so it's anyone's guess what register you are talking about.  It may indeed be falsetto (which by training can be taken rather low although at significant loss of volume), it may be vocal fry (which tends to be used only at rather low bass ranges and more often than not requires singing into a microphone to get useful levels), it may just be an airy quality of closure.